# Embed image in email body in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: html, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-email-ext

I need to add an image in email as email body not as attachment, from Jenkins via pipeline.
I am using emailext plugin in Jenkins pipeline, below is the code I am using.

```
emailext (
          subject: "test email",
          body: """
          <html>
          <body>
          <p>please find attached score: Job '${env.JOB_NAME}':</p>
          <p> The last commit was by ${last_commit_user} </p>
          <p>Please check jenkins console at "</p> 
          <p> For detailed report on this analysis, visit "</p>
          </body>
          </html>
          """,
          to: email_recipients,
          attachmentsPattern: '${BUILD_NUMBER}.jpg'
)
```

I do not want to use "attachmentsPattern" , that comes as an attachment,
I tried using,

```
body: """ 
<html>
<img src="image_name.jpg" >
</html>
"""
```

That comes only as blue box in my email , I am giving proper image path relative to my Jenkins workspace,
I tried to search relevant solutions but in vain.

Comment: Have you found a way to embed images in Jenkins email-ext?

Comment: did you find any solutions? i'm also having similar issues on my end

Comment: @Dinesh Please find my solution below, I was facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can either do this with base64 string of your image as correctly described earlier, or you can add your image as attachment in the email text and then reference this in your img src attribute.

Simple way to create html file (which will be your html body in the email) straight in the pipeline

```
 sh "echo '<b>Job Name: </b>${env.JOB_NAME}<br />' > mail.html"
 sh "echo '<b>Execution Result: </b>${currentBuild.currentResult}<br />' >> mail.html"
 sh "echo '<b>Build Number: </b> ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}<br />' >> mail.html"
 sh "echo '<b>Build URL: </b> ${env.BUILD_URL}<br />' >> mail.html"  
 sh "echo '<img src='cid:sample.jpg' alt='hello'>' >> mail.html"
```

1.) Add attachment into emailtext

```
   emailext attachmentsPattern: 'sample.jpg', 
   body: '${FILE,path="mail.html"}',
   to: "${emailRecipientsList}",
   recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']],
   subject: "Jenkins Build ${currentBuild.currentResult}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME}",
   mimeType: 'text/html'
```

2.) Reference the image in attachment in your img src attribude

```
<img src='cid:sample.jpg' alt='hello'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your image to Base64. I do it using python.

```
import base64

base64Img = ''

with open("image.png", "rb") as imageFile:
    base64Img = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

with open("image.html", "wb+") as writer:
    writer.write('<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.encode())
    writer.write(base64Img)
    writer.write('">'.encode())
```

This writes a file ''image.html''. This file you can then append into your <body>. In my pipeline I do it like so:

```
${FILE,path="image.html"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not add an image in .png format. Instead you can add the encoded base64 formatted image inside your html data.

To convert your actual image into base64, use [LINK](https://onlinepngtools.com/convert-png-to-base64) here.
Source need to be changed.

```
body:"""
<html>
<img src="data:image/png;base64<BASE64_ENCODED_IMAGE>" >
</html>
"""
```

In above code 'BASE64_ENCODED_IMAGE' is base64 convered code obtained from above link.

Please see the link for [Embed Base64-Encoded Images Inline In HTML](https://bigfastblog.com/embed-base64-encoded-images-inline-in-html)

Answer (score -2):

Push the image file in workspace directory of jenkins job.
Goto the workspace and click on the image to get the URL.
Place `img src="IMAGE_URL"` in email template.